# IUPAC naming molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Can someone help me name these 3 molecules (they may be only hypothetical)?

[image: Photograph showing 3 examples of molecules]

Comment: I have only guessed at the order of functional groups

Comment: How did you arrive at your suggested names? Have you tried searching for the IUPAC priority rules?   If you search chem.SE for posts written by @Loong there are many worked through examples of this kind of thing that may allow you to answer your own question.

Comment: Please see our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).

Answer (score 4):

You have already found out that the carboxylic acid group is the principal characteristic group, which is expressed at the end of a name by means of a suffix or a class name.

You have also found the correct names for the parent structures **butanoic acid** and **but-3-enoic acid,** respectively.

Furthermore, you have correctly started the numbering at the carboxylic acid groups since low locants are given first to the principal characteristic group; thus, the numbering starts at the carboxylic acid groups.

The remaining problem is the order of citation of substituent prefixes. Simple prefixes are arranged alphabetically disregarding any multiplicative prefixes. Any multiplicative prefixes are inserted later and do not alter the alphabetical order.

The corresponding actual wording of the nomenclature rules (taken from *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*) reads as follows.

> **P-14.5** ALPHANUMERICAL ORDER
>
> Alphanumerical order has been commonly called ‘alphabetical order’. As these ordering principles do involve ordering both letters and numbers, in a strict sense, it is best called ‘alphanumerical order’ in order to convey the message that both letters and numbers are involved
>
> Alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of detachable substituent prefixes (not the detachable saturation prefixes, hydro and dehydro), and the numbering of a chain, ring, or ring system when a choice is possible.
>
> (…)
>
> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Therefore, the names for the compounds that are given in the question are **4-bromo-3-methylbutanoic acid,** **4-bromo-4-hydroxy-3-methylbutanoic acid,** and **(3*Z*)-4-bromo-4-hydroxy-3-methylbut-3-enoic acid.**